# refering to a QString

Tags: c++, qt

In QT 5.2 how do I get a QString pointer to the data in a QLineEdit ?

For example, a function exists, that accepts pointer to a QString:

```
void SomeClass::do_something(QString *qptr) {

    qWarning() << "string is " << qptr;
}
```

so, I have an object which is a QLineEdit and I want the pointer to its text for reading purposes (I am not going to modify it):

```
fld_title=new QLineEdit();
/// open a window and work with fld_title so title is set
/// 
some_obj->do_something(fld_title->text()); <<-- produces compile error
```

I declare do_something() function to receive a pointer and not the object itself because I don't want the compiler to pass the entire object to the function in the arguments, it would be slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text()` returns a `QString` value, not a pointer, so you can't pass it directly to your function.

The best option is to change your function to take a value, `QString`, or reference `const QString &`. The `const` is necessary for a reference parameter, to allow the argument to be a constant.

> I don't want the compiler to pass the entire object to the function in the arguments, it would be slower.

Copy elision, and move semantics (if Qt supports them), mean that it probably isn't slower. But if you are concerned about speed, and you find that passing by value is a bottleneck, then passing by reference should be just as fast as passing a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`QLineEdit.text()` returns a `QString` not a `QString *`.  You need to change your code to take a `QString` or `const QString &`.

Comment: @  Mike Seymour I removed the incorrect code and just suggested he should change his function.

Comment: Also, it needs to be `const QString &` to allow a temporary argument.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
void SomeClass::do_something(const QString& str ) {
    qWarning() << "string is " << str;
}
```

And just use QLineEdit::text().

EDIT:Other answer was changed. :)

Answer (score 0):

> In QT 5.2 how do I get a QString pointer to the data in a QLineEdit ?

Basically you cannot. API give you only a copy of QString object.

But QString is cheap to copy as it utilizes copy on write principle. It means that until you will not change your copy of QString it is cheap to have as many copies of it as you want. Those will be shallow copies.

Passing object has other positive aspects as code readability and maintanability (in case of pointer you always have to define who is responsible for memory dealocation)

Answer (score 0):

Generally QObjects or any well desinged class will NOT give you access via a pointer to their members. It kills the classes encapsulation and is considered bad design. You will get a copy, as in this case QLineEdit::text() and you can use the copy to work with. 
The problem with passing arround raw pointers is as well, that you don't know exactly which object owns the memory behind the pointer and should delete it. 
If I need to really pass arround dynamically allocated objects (and their ownership), I would use a smart pointer as QSharedPointer etc. 
If the ownership is not passed to another object, so I need the object only to call its functions, I prefer a reference to the object to access it or do it with really loose coupling and connect the two objects with Qt signal/slots. 
In this case the two objects communicating don't even need a pointer/reference to the other one...